# I am trying to set the image size to the size of the button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set the size of the image according to the size of the button.See my following code in html:

```
<button id="image" type="button" title="Image">
    <img src = "nature.jpg" width="20" height="20" />
</button>
```

But I am not getting it.
Can you please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the code? Update your question properly

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: You can use image as background of button.. and set background size

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove button padding and border to make image fill it completely.

```
#image {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nfpNL/1/

You can also set image as a background:

```
#image {
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

then you will not need `img` tag at all

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nfpNL/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the style of the img to inherit from parent using

```
 <img src = "nature.jpg" style="width:inherit;height:inherit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you better take help of css for doing this perfectly..

```
#image{
background-image: url(nature.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: <left|right>;
padding-<left|right>: <width of image>px;
}
```

It's usually a little easier to use a button with an img inside:

```
<button id="image" type="button" title="Image">
</button>
```